# Struct field level permissions

Tags: go, go-gin, sqlx

I am playing with gin-gonic+sqlx. Now I wonder what is the best way to dynamically bind database records to the struct?

Saying I have a struct and a query like this.

```golang
type Project struct {
    ID        string    `db:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `db:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt NullTime  `db:"deleted_at"`
    Name      string
    Status    string
    OpenDate  NullTime `db:"open_date"`
    Number    uint
}

func (p Project) List() ([]Project, error) {
    var pp []Project
    err := db.Select(&pp, "SELECT * FROM Project")
    return pp, err
}
```

Now I want to add field-level permissions to this struct. For example, an admin can view and edit all fields; User A can view `CreatedAt` and `Name`; User B can view and edit `Name` `Status` and view `Number`.

I was writing multiply structs for each use case, but obviously, I did choose the silliest way.
The other method I can think of is to implement Struct Tag. Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want these permissions reflected in the database? Or just at the application level?

Comment: @Flimzy Only application level. All the fields are in one table

Comment: Okay. That's much simpler. It also makes the SQL component of the question irrelevant (which is why it's simpler!)

Answer (score 0):

We can create multiple structs and embed among each other.
Example:

```golang
type ProjectSummary struct {
    ID   string `db:"id"`
    Name string
}

type ProjectUser struct {
    ProjectSummary
    CreatedAt time.Time `db:"created_at"`
}

type ProjectSupport struct {
    ProjectSummary
    Status string
    Number uint
}

type ProjectAdmin struct {
    ProjectSupport
    CreatedAt time.Time `db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `db:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt NullTime  `db:"deleted_at"`
    OpenDate  NullTime  `db:"open_date"`
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I am doing now. I just feel it is somehow not elegant enough. Because it is not easy to track and modify.